# how to get data from url in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to get data from url and show in a textView , But after receiving, it only shows html codes.

I use a Educational video but my result is wrong.

I used another methods too but all result are same and just show html codes.

**MainActivity :**

```
public static final String SAMPLE_URL = "http://nimatest.epizy.com/ffff.json";

findViewById(R.id.btn_get_data).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           new TaskGetData().execute(SAMPLE_URL);
       }
   });

public class TaskGetData extends AsyncTask<String , String , String>{

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    textView.append("Get data ...\n\n");
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    return MyHttpUtils.getDataHttpUriConnection(params[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    textView.append(result + "\n");
    }
}
```

**MyHttpUtils :**

```
public static String getDataHttpUriConnection(String uri){
    try {
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        String result = inputStreamToString(con.getInputStream());
        return result;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public static String inputStreamToString(InputStream stream)  {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = "";
    try
    {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: As per the above code, it will provide you only html code, what are you expecting from the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. It reads HTML from a URL

> This site requires Javascript to work

HttpUrlConnection does not use or render dynamic Javascript created web pages, only static html content

Try a different endpoint for JSON data...

Also, please look into using a proper HTTP library for Android rather than using AsyncTask like Okhttp or Volley